# Skip function execution based on a condition

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, decorator

Could you please help in suggestion a better approach for code written at line no 10-11, as it's not a good way to have multiple `if __name__ == "__main__":` blocks across the same file.

Also I can keep the code `read_argument()` inside `setupClass` but I do not want to do so, as doing so code at line 29 `ignoreThisTestCase` simply becomes ineffective (decorators get evaluated before `setUpClass` is called - checked using debug)

`read_argument() - This is a method using argparser for initializing the value of env`

**Code Block:**

```
1  import unittest
2  from utils import read_argument, ignoreThisTestCase
3  from unittest import TestCase
4  env = ''
5  option_list = ['dev', 'prod', 'stage']
6  class TestMethods(TestCase):
7     """
8     A basic simple test class using only unittest
9     """
10    if __name__ == "__main__":
11        read_argument(dev_options=option_list)
12    @classmethod
13    def setUpClass(cls):
14        print("setUpClass")
15
16    @classmethod
17    def tearDownClass(cls):
18        print("tearDownClass")
19
20    def test_001_upper(self):
21        """This is explanation of the Test case no 1
22        and it works fine
23
24        """
25
26        print(f'\t\t\texec : {self._testMethodName}')
27        self.assertEqual('bar'.upper(), 'BAR')
28
29    @ignoreThisTestCase(env == 'stage', "will work in staging")
30    def test_002_isupper(self):
31        """This is explanation of the Test case no 2
32        and it works fine
33
34        """
35        print(f'\t\t\tRunning test: {self._testMethodName}')
36        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
37        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())
38
39 if __name__ == '__main__':
40
41    unittest.main()
```

I have already tried writing a decorator & `unitttest` mock, but looks like decorators are not allowed at class-level statements.

Comment: Please, explain what is your goal. It's not clear what `read_argument` does.

Comment: What *problem are you trying to solve*? Why should the behaviour change depending on whether `__name__ == "__main__"`? If this code represents test cases to be used by the test runner, then why *would* you ever be running it as the main script?

Comment: actually ignorethistestcase is a decorator which is meant ignore the test case - Not even let it enter the unittest pipeline (unlike skip) , So it gets evaluated before setupclass gets called

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`skipIf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf) feature from `unittest` standard lib. You can define some condition and must write some reason (string).

**calc.py**

```py
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**test_calc.py**

```py
import unittest

from calc import plus

env = 'dev'


class TestPlusMethod(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass")

    def test_positive_numbers(self):
        self.assertEquals(plus(1, 1), 2)

    @unittest.skipIf(env == 'dev', 'Some reason...')
    def test_negative_numbers(self):
        self.assertEqual(plus(-1, -1), -2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This should be the result

```sh
/ # python test_app.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=1)
```